# How many liters of oil do you use for servicing?

Tags: honda, accord, oil-change

Honda Accord 2003 V6 service maintenance?

Answer (score 4):

Google even show the details as a separate break out now

https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=honda%20accord%202006%20v6%20oil%20capacity

[image: Search result]

Comment: Please include the answer ... as it stands, this could be closed as a "link only" answer.

Comment: Haha! The image is a nice touch, but you could have just added the information. As long as you cite your source (which you did), nobody will fault you for using the information. Thanks for taking my advice, though. It makes the answer much more complete.